# Model binding a list of checkboxes problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, model-binding, mvc-editor-templates

In my EditorTemplates, i Have two Views. One for my Category (called _Category)

```
@model com.example.Models._Category
@Html.CheckBox(Model.Name, Model.Selected)
@Html.LabelFor(c => c.Name, Model.Name)
<br />
```

and one for the List of Categories (called _Categories)

```
@model List<com.example.Models._Category>
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(c => Model[i]);
}
```

In the view that shows these categories, i have a list of Categories which is being used like so:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Categories, "_Categories")
```

When I view the page, there are multiple checboxes with names next to them which is good. The name of the checkboxes is not so good however as they turn out to look like this:

`....name="Categories.[1].Batman"....">`

There is an extra dot in the name which needs to go away. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

Please refer to [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) and [this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx) for collections databinding, those are two ultimate resources for that.

Answer (score 3):

I saw [this post](http://btburnett.com/2011/03/correcting-mvc-3-editorfor-template-field-names-when-using-collections.html) that I believe talks about the same issue that you are having.  Might be helpful.