# when passing a collection to EditorFor(), it generates invalid names for input elements

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, model-binding, editorfor

I have a BookCreateModel which consists of book's plane info such as Title, PublishYear & etc plus a collection of book Authors (complex type) :

```
public class BookCreateModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public IList<AuthorEntryModel> Authors { get; set; }
}

public class AuthorEntryModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

in CreateBook view I have used `EditorFor` helper :

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Authors, "AuthorSelector")
```

### Edit1:

and AuthorSelector template is as below:

```
<div class="ptr_authors_wrapper">
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
       <div class="ptr_author_line" data-line-index="@i">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(o => o[i].FirstName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(o => o[i].LastName)
       </div>
    }
</div>
<script>
     ...
</script>
```

the `AuthorSelector` template contains some wrapper markups which need to be aware of each rendered item's index plus some javascript which handle the child input's interactions and need to be rendered once (inside the `AuthorSelector` template), thus getting rid of the for loop/or the AuthorSelector template is not possible.

now the problem is EditorFor act a little strange and generate input names like this :

```
<input id="Authors__0__FirstName" name="Authors.[0].FirstName" type="text" value="" />
<input id="Authors__0__LastName" name="Authors.[0].LastName" type="text" value="" />
```

as you can see instead of generating names like `Authors[0].FirstName` it adds an extra dot  which makes the default model binder unable to parse posted data.

any idea ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 8):

I would recommend you sticking to conventions, i.e. replace:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Authors, "AuthorSelector")
```

with:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Authors)
```

and then rename your `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/AuthorSelector.cshtml` to `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/AuthorEntryModel.cshtml` and make it strongly typed to a single `AuthorEntryModel` model and get rid of the loop:

```
@model AuthorEntryModel
@Html.TextBoxFor(o => o.FirstName)
@Html.TextBoxFor(o => o.LastName)
```

ASP.NET MVC will automatically render the editor template for all elements of the collection and generate proper names.

---

UPDATE:

After seeing your update here's my response:

In your main view:

```
<div class="ptr_authors_wrapper">
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Authors)
</div>
```

In your editor template:

```
@model AuthorEntryModel
<div class="ptr_author_line">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(o => o.FirstName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(o => o.LastName)
</div>
```

You will notice the absence of script in the template which is perfectly normal. Scripts have nothing to do in markup. They go into separate javascript files. In this file you could use jQuery to do whatever you need to do with your markup. It gives you methods such as `.index()` that allow you to get the index of the element in the matched selector so that you don't need to write any loops and pollute your markup with things like `data-line-index` attributes.

Comment: thanks, the AuthorSelector also generates some wrapper markup for each item so replacing the for loop with new syntax is not possible. I updated the question, please take a look

Comment: yep, that's also an option, but I think purpose of using EditorTemplate is to encapsulates bunch of markups and codes which free the developer from repeating himself over and over. the wrapper div in this case is a simplified example; in reality it's much more longer, imagine how hard it would be to copy/paste that piece of markups over and over in different places.

Comment: @sos00, yes, this is exactly the purpose of an editor temlpate => encapsulate a reusable markup. I say markup, not scripts. Scripts go into separate (and if you will reusable) javascript files. You could write plugins and so on to make your scripts reusable.

Comment: Thank you :), I meant markups too, not scripts. your solution requires the developer to copy **markups** everywhere he wants to get a collection of Author items. anyway I was hopping to see if this is a known bug and someone knows any workaround for it, so I voted your answer up but will wait a little more to see if anyone has any more info on this bug(?).

Comment: Using the editor templates allows you to provide a template for each item in the collection.


As far as I can see you can't define a template for the collection as a whole (let's say you want a header and footer) from which you can then call the editor template for the items _without_ having the problem of the additional dot in the input prefix.


@sos00's solution of adding a wrapper class works, but it does feel like a work-around.

Answer (score 7):

I'm a little late to the party, but hopefully this helps someone.

Digging down to `System.Web.Mvc.Html.DefaultEditorTemplates.CollectionTemplate(HtmlHelper html, TemplateHelpers.TemplateHelperDelegate templateHelper)`, the framework's default template handles this by temporarily setting the `HtmlFieldPrefix` to an empty string and explicitly passing the prefix and index into a call to `EditorFor()`.

```
<div class="ptr_authors_wrapper">
@{
    var prefix = ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix;

    ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = String.Empty;

    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
        <div class="ptr_author_line" data-line-index="@i">
            @* You can also use null instead of "TextBox" to let the framework resolve which editor to use. *@
            @Html.EditorFor(o => o[i].FirstName, "TextBox", String.Format("{0}[{1}].FirstName", prefix, i))
            @Html.EditorFor(o => o[i].LastName, "TextBox", String.Format("{0}[{1}].LastName", prefix, i))
        </div>
    }

    ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = prefix;
}
</div>
<script>
     ...
</script>
```

I found this particularly useful when the framework was writing names as `[0].Children.[0].ChildProperty` due to a named template for the Children collection. In my case, the solution was to call:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m[i], null, String.Format("{0}[{1}]", prefix, i))
```

rather than simply calling:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m[i])
```

Comment: Thanks much for this.  Your response just made my morning.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if it's still relevant, but this blog covers a solution to your problem:
http://btburnett.com/2011/03/correcting-mvc-3-editorfor-template-field-names-when-using-collections.html

--> Credits go to [itsmatt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7114739/1499046) for finding it :)
Jakob

Answer (score 1):

Here's an extension method you can use which will render a partial view and use the correct HTML field prefix:

**Extension Method**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Helper method that renders the specified partial view as a HTML-encoded string using the specified
    /// collection as the model, with the intention that the partial view will use an editor template on the items
    /// in the collection.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TModel">the model type</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TProperty">the property type</typeparam>
    /// <param name="htmlHelper">the <see cref="HtmlHelper"/> instance</param>
    /// <param name="partialViewName">the name of the partial view to render</param>
    /// <param name="collectionExpression">the model collection property expression</param>
    /// <returns>the HTML-encoded string</returns>
    public static MvcHtmlString PartialContainingEditorForCollection<TModel, TProperty>
        (this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, string partialViewName,
         Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> collectionExpression)
        where TProperty : IEnumerable
    {
        var viewData = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData;
        var model = (TModel) viewData.Model;
        var collection = collectionExpression.Compile().Invoke(model);

        var htmlFieldPrefix = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(
            ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(collectionExpression));

        return htmlHelper.Partial(partialViewName, collection,
                                  new ViewDataDictionary
                                      {
                                          TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo {HtmlFieldPrefix = htmlFieldPrefix}
                                      });
    }
```

**Sample Usage**

```
@Html.PartialContainingEditorForCollection("_TableWithSummary", m => Model.FormModel.ItemsToOrder)
```

Comment: Could you please put parent view and child view ?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any solution to this bug yet, but as a workaround I changed my `UpdateModel` by using a custom wrapper class instead of using a collection directly :

```
public class BookCreateModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public BookAuthorsList Authors { get; set; }
}

public class BookAuthorsList
{
    public IList<AuthorEntryModel> AuthorsList { get; set; }
}

public class AuthorEntryModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

and thus generated inputs wouldn't make naming issues anymore :)

```
<input  id="Authors_AuthorsList_0__FirstName" name="Authors.AuthorsList[0].FirstName" type="text"/>
<input  id="Authors_AuthorsList_0__LastName" name="Authors.AuthorsList[0].LastName" type="text"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this when I was trying to find the solution for pretty much the same issue. My workaround was to kick the can down the road, ie. make wrapper model for the collection and use that in the editor template. In provided case, it would be:

```
public class BookCreateModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public BookAuthorsModel Authors { get; set; }
}

public class BookAuthorsModel
{
    IList<AuthorEntryModel> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Then rename your editor template to "BookAuthorsModel.cshtml" and make it like this:

```
@model BookAuthorsModel
<div class="ptr_authors_wrapper">
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Items.Count; i++)
    {
       <div class="ptr_author_line" data-line-index="@i">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(o => Items.o[i].FirstName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(o => Items.o[i].LastName)
       </div>
    }
</div>
<script>
     ...
</script>
```

And when you want to use it, simply call:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Authors)
```

It should then generate input fields like so:

```
<input id="Authors_Items_0__FirstName" name="Authors.Items[0].FirstName" type="text" value="" />
<input id="Authors_Items_0__LastName" name="Authors.Items[0].LastName" type="text" value="" />
```

In my case I also changed Automapper mapping settings appropriately Controller code.
This is not usable for some more complex scenarios however and is thus probably just a workaround.