# MVC5 with EF6 : EditorFor() with an ICollection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, editorfor, icollection

I have a problem with my MVC5/EF6 website. I have a model like this :

[image: model]
<sub>(source: [hostingpics.net](http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/330453Capturestackoverflow.png))</sub>

When I'm creating an activity, I would like to add at least one date to it. So I created a new field in the form :

```
<div class="form-group">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Days, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
     <div class="col-md-10">
         @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Days)
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Days)
     </div>
</div>
```

According to various sources I've read here and there (https://stackoverflow.com/a/11403858/360708), I must create a file Day.cshtml in View/Shared/EditorTemplates/ so that I can tell MVC I want Day to have an editor for "day1" (DatePicker here).

This is because my model Day is an ICollection inside Activity, so I can't access the field day1 like this : "model.Days.day1". I've tried creating the Day.cshtml but it doesn't work. Here's the content of Day.cshtml

```
@model GAS_VS2013.Models.Day

@Html.EditorFor(o => o.day1)
```

Am I forgetting something or doing something wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: You are not passing the path to your template as parameter of EditorFor.

Comment: Thank you Fals. Well, now I have my form with my datepicker correctly shown, but when I click submit, when I check in debug mode, the activity object has it's Days field to null. How can I retrieve the date value ?

Comment: for now, I stopped using EditorFor(model => model.Days, "Day") to use a basic HTML 5 <input name="day" id="day" type="date"/> from which I get the value in the controller with "Request["day"].ToString()". I don't take advantage of EF but at least it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Fals](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2072198/fals), it's now working with :

```
<div class="form-group">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Days, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
     <div class="col-md-10">
         @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Days, "Day")
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Days)
     </div>
</div>
```

To display the textbox as a HTML5 DatePicker, don't forget to add a DateTime.cshtml in the EditorTemplates with the following code (type of your day field must be DateTime) :

```
@model Nullable<DateTime>
@{
   DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
   if (Model != null)
   {
      dt = (System.DateTime)Model;
   }
   @Html.TextBox("", String.Format("{0:d}", dt.ToShortDateString()), new { @class = "form-control datecontrol", type = "date" })
}
```

Source : http://www.aubrett.com/InformationTechnology/WebDevelopment/MVC/DatePickerMVC5.aspx(